# How can I create a VSCode snippets extension for text files?

Tags: text-files, vscode-extensions

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "trsnippets",
  "displayName": "testRigor Snippets",
  "description": "Snippets for the most common commands on the testRigor tool.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.76.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Snippets"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "txt",
        "path": "./snippets/snippets.code-snippets"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I chose `txt` as the language when creating the folders with yeoman, but it doesn't consider text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `language identifier` for text files: `plaintext`, not `txt`.  The language identifier is not the file extension.

If you hover over the `"language"` key it tells you that.  And then to find the `languageID` or language identifier for text files: open a `.txt` file and look in the lower right-hand corner of the editor and you'll see `Plain Text` - but you would use `plaintext` as the language identifier.

Which you can see if you click on that `Plain Text` text (it is a button) and look for `plain text` in the dropdown window.  The languageID is that part in parentheses at the end of each filetype line like `(plaintext)`.